# How to get Django forms data and use it for further processing and rendering?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am very new to Django and learning with my own I am able to build few basic app and I can say my concept about Django views, urls and models are quite clear but forms are quite confusing topic for me. And I am not able to deal with it.. Lets assume one situation.

I have created one form "Calculator" gets two values from user with the mathematical operator addition, subtraction or multiplication :

example:

My form:

```
value_1 = 8
Value_2 = 6
Math_op = +
```

now I define a calculator function in views which gets values from the form and do some math and generates results like this

```
Answers = 14
```

Now I want to transfer this result or answers variables value to a new webpage to show out put of calculator event.

My confusion is that how can I define a url for this case and how can i define a method which takes value from template  and render this value to another form template.

Code i have used, is given bello: **UPDATED CODE**

Forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):


    first_value = forms.CharField(label='First Value', max_length=100)
    Second_value = forms.CharField(label='Second Value', max_length=100)
    operator     = forms.CharField(label='Operator', max_length=100)
```

Views.py

```
rom django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NameForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            value_1 = form.cleaned_data['first_value']
            value_2 = form.cleaned_data['Second_value']
            ope = form.cleaned_data['operator']

            if ope == "+":
                ans = int(value_1) + int(value_2)
            elif ope == "-":
                ans = int(value_1) - int(value_2)
            elif ope == "*":
                ans = int(value_1) * int(value_2)

            else:
                print "Values are not correct"

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ans_page/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'PEP/name.html', {'form': form})

def ans_page(request):
   ans = request.session['ans']
   return render(request,'PEP/ans.html',{'ans':ans})
```

Urls:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name='get_name'),
    url(r'^/ans_page$', views.ans_page, name='ans_page'),
    ]
```

templates:

```
<form action="/ans_page/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Template 2: ans.html

```
{% if  ans %}
{{ ans }}
{% endif %}
```

Error:

```
KeyError at /ans_page/
'ans'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ans_page/
Django Version: 1.10
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'ans'
Exception Location: /home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __getitem__, line 57
Python Executable:  /home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/src',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jai/Desktop/Django_form/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Jul 2017 08:44:15 +0000
```

Comment: this is a long process, as for this you need 2 views , 2 url routes and one form

Comment: @Exprator I have updated my code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have mostly done all the parts, except that you need another view function and a url to display the result,

so in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name='get_name'),
    url(r'^/ans_page$', views.ans_page, name='ans_page'), // add this
    ]
```

create a view

```
def ans_page(request):
    ans = request.session['ans']
    return render(request,'PEP/ans.html',{'ans':ans})
```

and in `ans.html`

```
{% if  ans %}
{{ ans }}
{% endif %}
```

and in get_name view

```
request.session['ans'] = ans
return HttpResponseRedirect('/ans_page/')
```

and change the form to this

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: thank for your response i have made the changes but its showing error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/your-name/
Using the URLconf defined in pep_learn.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='get_name']
^ans_page$ [name='ans_page']
The current URL, your-name/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Why does we use this line <form action="/your-name/" method="post"> and  "your-name" variable

Comment: in the form action you need to put action='/ans_page/' @jax, i overlooked that, editing my ans

Comment: Yehhh i was thinking this should be change. Thanks a lot.

Comment: one more strange thing its rendering the page "ans.html" now from the view "ans_page" but not showing the calculated result on the page when i put a simple <h1> hi </h> its shows "hii" but not the value of "ans" variable.

Comment: how are you using the redirection?? means how are you sending the data to ans-page?

Comment: with this line as u suggested "return render(request,'PEP/ans.html',{'ans':ans})"

Comment: I just simply replaced "return HttpResponseRedirect('/ans_page/')"  with this "return render(request,'PEP/ans.html',{'ans':ans})"